# Helm uninstall failed: uninstall: Release not loaded: name: release: not found

Tags: kubernetes-helm, fluxcd

I am installing solr using flux on an AKS cluster. During installation I get reconciliation error.
when I do flux get all -A --status-selector ready=false, I get the below message
Helm uninstall failed: uninstall: Release not loaded: solr: release: not found.
When I do helm ls --all-namespaces
The release is not there as per the error message. When I check the chart, they are getting pulled fine and ready, no issues there. Question is why the release object not get created? Your responses are very much appreciated.
The below is the release file content

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: solr
  namespace: solr-test
spec:
  releaseName: solr
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: solr
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: nexus-helm
        namespace: flux-system
      version: "6.x"
  interval: 5m
  timeout: 12m
  install:
    remediation:
      retries: 3
```

I tried listing the helmchart helm ls --all-namespaces
I was expecting to see the charts listed , but nothing. Read a lot of articles, I could not find help or at least a hint at least. If flux can give more details on issues like this would be much helpful for beginners like myself

Comment: Could you add to the question the `HelmRepository` object for `nexus-helm`?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue.
In my case, I wasn't setting the chart version in the HelmRelease with my versions overlay. I had created a HelmRelease file, but hadn't included it in the kustomization.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening because the underline helm chart I was using had an issue which neither `helm lint` catched nor `helm upgrade --install ...` catched. I duplicated a key (replicas) in my deployment.yaml in chart.

After fixing that my flux release happens as usual.